# How to config Trackpoint + Synaptics touchpad only enable clicks on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, trackpoint

I have Thinkpad T440, which do not ship with the three buttons on the touchpad.

I used to use trackpoint with clicks on those three buttons. While in this T440 case, I want to disable the touchpad " MOVE | tap-to-click | two-finger or three-finger " features, and only config it like a big clickable buttons, with the middle one.

Can anyone tell me how to write it in **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/**

I have those files:

```
10-evdev.conf             11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  50-wacom.conf
10-quirks.conf            50-synaptics.conf         51-synaptics-quirks.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf      50-vmmouse.conf
```

Thanks in advance.

```
$xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I want to disable trackpad but with left right and middle "button" abled

Comment: Ah. Now that's possible, but a little tricky. Run `xinput list` in a terminal and edit the output into your answer.

Comment: I read the archlinux doc for it, but still confused about it. Do anyone have some examples?

Comment: Just run that command and I'll tell you what to do.

Comment: Already updated above

Comment: Wait. I just reread your comment. Do you want the TouchPad to still register touches, but not be able to move the cursor? I can tell you how to disable the TouchPad completely and keep the real buttons enabled, but not the half disable of the TouchPad. Is that OK?

Comment: The problem is for the T440 model, there is no physical real buttons. It is a one single touchpad. Sad about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not the direct answer, but a suggestion and examples.
If you run `xinput`, you will get list of your devices. Then run `xinput list-props $id` where `$id` is your touchpad id in the list.

You will have a list of options like this:

```
$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (135):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (137): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (268): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (269):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (270):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (292):  1765, 5371, 1637, 4453
    Synaptics Finger (293): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (294):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (295):   234
    Synaptics Tap Durations (296):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (297):   1
    [...]
```

You can change all of these on-the-fly with `xinput set-prop $id $propId $value` where `$id` is the device id, `$propId` is property id in brackets and `$value` is what you want it to be. For example:

`xinput set-prop 13 135 0` sets `Device Enabled (135)` to `0` and this will disable the touchpad.

You will need descriptions of properties and a way to make your changes permanent.
Descriptions can be found in `man synaptics`, but wait, they are in another cryptic format! Let's see why.

To make changes permanent, you need to create conf file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`, for example `30-tochpad.conf` with contents like these:

```
    Section "InputClass"  # you can read more in `man xorg`
            Identifier "all touchpads"  # just a name for this config
            MatchIsTouchpad "on"  # enables this config for all detected touchpads
            Driver "synaptics"  # enables synaptics-specific options below

            # This will disable the device
            #Option "Ignore" "1"

            # There are options that are generic for input-devices or mouse-like devices, see `man evdev`:
            Option "ButtonMapping" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0"  # i disabled all buttons here, for example

            # Here go options from `man synaptics`
            Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1"
            Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1"
            Option "PalmDetect" "1"
            Option "ClickPad" "0"                
            # ...etc...
    EndSection
```

So, `man synaptics` describes options for `xorg.conf` and tells how they correspond to `xinput list-props` output.

PS. I tried to configure trackpoint on my ThinkPad X220 to have only two-fingers-scroll enabled, without clicks or mouse movement. I failed. Maybe you will manage to do what you want (there was an option to disable everything but clicks, maybe `Synaptics Off`).

Sources, more examples and unicorns:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively You could download the **"GnomeTweakTool"** and configure or deactivate it under Mouse&Keyboard > Click Emulation.