# Package to configure Trackpoint on Dell Latitude E6410?

Tags: package-management, dell, trackpoint

I have a Dell Latitude E6410 running latest Ubuntu 15.04 (see Details at the end of this question). I think I have the same problem with the TrackPoint as described in:

[Dell vs Lenovo trackpoint/nipple/trackstick mouse drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639606/dell-vs-lenovo-trackpoint-nipple-trackstick-mouse-drivers)

A comment left on that question is:
 [Dell vs Lenovo trackpoint/nipple/trackstick mouse drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639606/dell-vs-lenovo-trackpoint-nipple-trackstick-mouse-drivers#comment986550_639606)

and that points to

[Settings for Glidepoint touchpad/trackpoint on Dell Latitude](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428602/settings-for-glidepoint-touchpad-trackpoint-on-dell-latitude)

But reading through that link leaves me confused as to how to actually install that package from the Ubuntu repositories (and I mean install it without a lot of effort such as downloading and building from source packages).

Searching on the web shows http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/input/4932/input%3AAlpsPS/2ALPSGlidePoint/ 
which talks about a certified laptop. E6410 is not listed.

Searching for glidepoint package reveals:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/touchpad-glidepoint

which says that:

> There is no current release for this source package in Ubuntu.

Is that the correct package to install? I'm concluding "no" because of the above comment.  If that is not the correct package, which one should I use? If it is the correct package, then why the "no current release" message?

### Detailed info:

Version of Ubuntu from `cat /etc/issue`:

```
Ubuntu 15.04 \n \l
```

`lspci` shows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
04:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 03)
04:00.4 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 03)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

`xinput list` shows:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_3M                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xinput list-props 'DualPoint Stick'` shows:

```
Device 'DualPoint Stick':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 2
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (260):    2, 8
    Device Node (261):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (304): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (306):  0
    Axis Labels (307):  "Rel X" (152), "Rel Y" (153)
    Button Labels (308):    "Button Left" (145), "Button Middle" (146), "Button Right" (147), "Button Wheel Up" (148), "Button Wheel Down" (149), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (150), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (151)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (309): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (310):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (311):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (312): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (313): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (314):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (315):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (316):    1
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (317):   6, 7, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (318):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (319):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (320): 2
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (321):  0
```

Settings only shows what is marked in red:

[image: Settings view]

And that does not show any widgets that allow me to control TrackPoint behavior, which is what led me to believe something was missing, and therefore, that I needed to hunt down and install some special packages:

[image: Mouse and Touchpad view]

Comment: any progress here?

Comment: None. I unfortunately had to give up on it as I needed to buy a new laptop that did not have a Trackpoint (only a trackpad).

Answer (score 0):

To disable the DualPoint Stick on the Latitude, open Terminal and type:

```
xinput disable 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick'
```

Comment: My goal at that time was to configure the trackpoint to work as smoothly as it does under Windows. The goal was not to disable the trackball.